# How to remove scratches from a DVD or CD disk?

Tags: cleaning

DVD or CD disks can have scratches.

When I want to watch a movie, they interrupt the replay.

How do I remove  the scratches or buffer the playback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Using Toothpaste:"

Choose a basic toothpaste. There's no need for the sparkles, swirls, and exotic flavors of some oral care products. Instead, opt for a basic white paste to polish your CD. All types of toothpaste contain enough abrasive minerals to get the job done!
Basic toothpastes are cheaper than their flashier alternatives. This can be especially helpful if you have several CD's to polish.

Apply toothpaste to the CD surface. Squeeze a small dab of toothpaste onto the scratched surface of your CD and spread it evenly over the surface of the CD with your finger.

Polish the CD. Using a radial motion, slowly work the toothpaste around the CD. Start at the center and move in a straight line outward.

Clean and dry the CD. Run the CD under some warm water and rinse thoroughly. Then, using a soft, clean cloth, dry the CD and double check to make sure you've removed all traces of toothpaste or moisture.
After you've cleaned and dried the CD, use a soft cloth to buff the surface of the CD.

For more information kindly see the following link:

https://www.google.com.pk/amp/s/m.wikihow.com/Fix-a-Scratched-CD%3famp=1

Comment: It's worth noting you have to polish the plastic side of the CD, NOT the label side.